# intertitial ads only show one time and not load again

Tags: android-studio

why my intertitial ads only show one ads, and not load again?

android studio, can i add more code to always load after show ads?

i want my ads always working fine, when load after show one ads, and then ready again to load ads.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.